# Retrieving Entities from Core Data: Printing properties gives me incomplete/unwanted results?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, printing, attributes

I've recently decided to move all my application data from plists to Core Data. This was pretty straightforward. I had a class with a couple properties I would read all my plist info to using a dictionary. This was mimicked by creating an entity with the same exact attributes. I then loaded the plist information into Arrays, and parsed them all, writing and save new entities to core data.

Sounds good no? Well, I thought to so. However, now that I'm reading it all back in, I've noticed some problems.

For one, when I go ahead and try to print off the properties of my object as follows:

```
for (CXStellarObject *obj in self.starsArray)
{
    NSLog(@"Type: %@\n Language: %@\n Name: %@\n ImageName: %@\n Description: %@\n",obj.type,obj.language.label,obj.name,obj.imageName,obj.description);
}
```

I get this:

```
Type: star
 Language: (null)
 Name: Sirius
 ImageName: 
 Description: <CXStellarObject: 0x7fbb0a58d5d0> (entity: CXStellarObject; id: 0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://9E3F584C-3214-4A6A-B55A-B63D066A152B/CXStellarObject/p5> ; data: {
    descriptor = "The brighest star visible from Earth, Sirius (Also known as Sirius A, or the Dog Star), is a bright white dwarf. It is part of the Canis Major Constellation. It is approximately 8.6 light years from o";
    imageName = "";
    language = "0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://9E3F584C-3214-4A6A-B55A-B63D066A152B/CXLocalizationAsset/p1>";
    name = Sirius;
    type = star;
})
```

For one, my description isn't even complete. It cuts off at "from o", when it actually goes on longer in the plist. Next, name and type are repeated at the bottom of the printed results. I don't know why they're there.

Finally, what are all these addresses and other junk flanking the resulting data? I don't want that there, how did it get there?

You're probably going to need to see what I've got going on here, so I'll show you the Entity that is involved: 
[image]

Here's how I wrote all these objects to Core Data:

```
-(void)writeAllArraysToCoreData
{
    NSArray *starsArray = [self starsArray];
    NSArray *planetsArray = [self planetsArray];
    NSArray *moonsArray = [self moonsArray];

    NSArray *allData = @[starsArray,planetsArray,moonsArray];
    for (NSArray *array in allData)
    {
        for (NSDictionary *dict in array)
        {
            [self archieveCXStellarObjectWithLanguage:[dict valueForKey:@"Language"] Type:[dict valueForKey:@"Type"] Name:[dict valueForKey:@"Name"] ImageName:[dict valueForKey:@"ImageName"] Descriptor:[dict valueForKey:@"Description"]];
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, the method called in here that I defined:

```
-(void)archieveCXStellarObjectWithLanguage:(NSString *)languageCode Type:(NSString *)type Name:(NSString *)name ImageName:(NSString *)imageName Descriptor:(NSString *)descriptor
{
    CXStellarObject *object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CXStellarObject" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [object setLanguage:[self.supportedLanguageAssets valueForKey:languageCode]];
    [object setType:type];
    [object setName:name];
    [object setImageName:imageName];
    [object setDescriptor:descriptor];
    // Add New Object to All Objects Array
    [self.allStoredObjects addObject:object];
    // Save Changes
    [self saveContext];

}
```

And finally how I extracted them, and where this is going a bit awry (Don't worry, it's not a complicated method)

```
-(void)loadData
{
    if (!self.allStoredObjects)
    {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CXStellarObject" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *fetchResults = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        if (!fetchResults)
        {
            [NSException raise:@"Fetch Failed!" format:@"Reason: %@",[error localizedDescription]];
        }
        [self setAllStoredObjects:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:fetchResults]];

        // Filter Arrays
        NSPredicate *starPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.type == 'star'"];
        [self setStarsArray:[fetchResults filteredArrayUsingPredicate:starPredicate]];
        for (CXStellarObject *obj in self.starsArray)
        {
            NSLog(@"Type: %@\n Language: %@\n Name: %@\n ImageName: %@\n Description: %@\n",obj.type,nil,obj.name,obj.imageName,obj.description);
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it, thanks for taking the time to get this far. If you need any more information from me, just comment and I'll put it in ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your CXStellarObject object is a custom subclass of NSManagedObject, you need to override the description method for that object and write it to return formatted info about your managed object.

Something like this:

-(NSString *) description;
{
  NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
  [result appendFormat: @"  descriptor = %@\n", self.descriptor];
  [result appendFormat: @"  imageName = %@\n", imageName];
  //And so on...
}

Comment: I was a fool, and was actually printing description in the NSLog call. That is what gave me the truncated results in the console. Changing `obj.description` to `obj.descriptor` (or vs on) fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest investigating Core Data "faults".  Whenever you see references like that in your descriptions that is because the object is not in memory yet, only a stub of the object is.  As soon as you touch the object Core Data will pull it into memory automatically and then the full values will be visible.

Further, it is common for long description calls to be clipped.  If you want to see the full value, capture it in the debugger and call it via `po`.